# MySQL Add Column with Online DDL

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm currently trying to add a column to a table of ~25m rows. I need to have near-0 down time, so was hoping to use online DDL. It runs for a while, but eventually runs into the issue:

```
"Duplicate entry '1234' for key 'PRIMARY'" 
[SQL: u'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_coumn BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT false']
```

I think this is happening because I'm running `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` operations against the table while running the operation. This seems to be a [known limitation](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76895).

After this didn't work, I tried using the Percona `pt-online-schema-change` tool, but unfortunately, because my table has generated columns, that didn't work either with error:

```
The value specified for generated column 'my_generated_column' in table '_my_table_new' is not allowed.
```

So, I'm now at a loss. What are my other options for adding a column without blocking DML operations?

Answer (score 3):

Your Alter statement is creating a non nullable column with a default of false.  I'd suspect this to place an exclusive lock on your table, attempt to create the column, then setting it to False across each row.

If you don't have any available downtime, I'd suggest you

1. Add the column as nullable and with no default

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_coumn BOOL NULL;
   ```
2. Update the values for existing rows to false

   ```
   update my_table set my_coumn=false;
   ```
3. Alter the table a second time to be not nullable and with a default.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table modify my_coumn BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
   ```

Alternatively you could use something like [Percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) which manages schema changes using triggers and is meant to offer the ability to update schemas without locking the table.

Either option I'd suggest you test in your development environment with some process writing to the table to simulate user activity.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I don't think you read the question. The error is about a duplicate entry and has nothing to do with anything being nullable. The question also explicitly says I tried using `pt-online-schema-change` (Percona), which you recommend I use.

Comment: Your specific question is, 'What are my other options for adding a column without blocking DML operations?', And the requirements provided were 'I need to have near-0 down time, so was hoping to use online DDL.' . This is what I tried to answer without any detailed DDL.  What I offered you is a method I've used in the past to limit impact for a column addition to an active table. If you want further feedback from me then send the specific ddl and table definition.  I'd also just mention that Percona tools are specifically made for this problem. Share how you used it and what error you receive.

Comment: You're still not reading the question. Every point you're making is either irrelevant to the question, or responded to in the question. I'm not trying to be rude here. I just really don't know what else to tell you.